# HMR in express - webpack config

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, webpack

I'm trying to set up HMR with my express sever. When I run `node app`, I see that webpack compiles, SQL seeds DB and node runs in my terminal . My app runs and seems to work, however when I make a change I don't see the change. I also don't see the change when I refresh the app either!

What am I missing? I think I'm close.

note: I'm following : http://andrewhfarmer.com/understanding-hmr/

**index.js:**

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import routes from './config/routes'

ReactDOM.render(
  routes,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

if (module.hot) {
  module.hot.accept();
}
```

**webpack.config**

```js
var webpack = require('webpack')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin")
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')

var HTMLWebpackPluginConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + '/index.html',
  filename: 'index_bundled.html',
  inject: 'body',
})

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    "jquery": __dirname + '/public/js/lib/jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js',
    "bootstrap": __dirname + '/public/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
    "index": [__dirname + '/app/index.js',
    'webpack-hot-middleware/client?path=/__webpack_hmr&timeout=2000&overlay=false'],
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public',
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: '/',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.js$/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: 'babel-loader'},
      {test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style!css?sourceMap&modules&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]'},
    ],
  },
  devtool: 'cheap-module-inline-source-map',
  plugins: [
    HTMLWebpackPluginConfig,
    new ExtractTextPlugin("dist/[name].css"),
    new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin()
  ]
}
```

**app.js**

```js
var express = require('express');

var webpack = require('webpack');
var webpackDevMiddleware = require("webpack-dev-middleware");
var webpackHotMiddleware = require("webpack-hot-middleware");
var compiler = webpack(require("./webpack.config.babel.js"));

/* Sequelize stuff */

var app = module.exports = express();

app.use(webpackDevMiddleware(compiler, {
  hot: true,
  filename: 'index.js',
  publicPath: '/',
  stats: {
    colors: true,
  },
  historyApiFallback: true,
}));

//app.use(require("webpack-hot-middleware")(compiler));

app.use(webpackHotMiddleware(compiler, {
  log: console.log,
  path: '/__webpack_hmr',
  heartbeat: 2000,
}));

/* APIs and routes */

// Starting express server
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```